# How Would A Carbosilicate Amorph move?

Tags: biology, science-fiction

How would a creature similar to a carbosilicate amorph from the Schlock Mercenary webcomic move?

Comment: this is more a question regarding a developed story rather than worldbuilding...

Comment: If you want to rework this question, I would a) describe the amorph's properties that interest you (questions should be self-contained where possible), and b) expand it to be about those properties in general, rather than this one specific example.

Answer (score 2):

It would probably be made of small flakes or strings of material that slide against each other.

The bits would be hard and immobile but the bits move against each other making the whole appear to be fluid.

If the bits are generally the same size and shape, a significant number can be lost without causing operational damage to the creature.

For such a creature, hunting would require having a higher cohesion so you can strip bits off of creatures with lower cohesion and grow.

Comment: The wiki agrees with you "Apparently he slides everywhere" http://schlockmercenary.wikia.com/wiki/Schlock